# Rails 4 create model with nested attributes has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a many to many relationship with `DoctorProfile` and `Insurance`. I'd like to create these associations off of a form from a client side app. I'm sending back an array of `doctor_insurances_ids` and trying to create the association in one line. Is it possible to send back an array of `doctor_insurances` ids? If so what's the proper way to name it for mass assignment in the params?

The error I'm getting with the following code is

`ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute 'doctor_insurances_ids' for DoctorProfile.`

```
class DoctorProfile
  has_many :doctor_insurances
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :doctor_insurances # not sure if needed

class Insurance < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :doctor_insurances

class DoctorInsurance < ActiveRecord::Base
  # only fields are `doctor_profile_id` and `insurance_id`
  belongs_to :doctor_profile
  belongs_to :insurance

def create
  params = {"first_name"=>"steve",
 "last_name"=>"johanson",
 "email"=>"steve@ymail.com",
 "password_digest"=>"password",
 "specialty_id"=>262,
 "doctor_insurances_ids"=>["44", "47"]}

  DoctorProfile.create(params)

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not putting a doctor_insurance_id in your Doctor Profile so your DoctorProfile.create(params) line isn't going to work.  You could do something like this:

```
def create
  doctor = DoctorProfile.create(doctor_profile_params)
  params["doctor_insurances_ids"].each do |x|
    DoctorInsurance.create(doctor_profile_id: doctor.id, insurance_id: x)
  end
end

def doctor_profile_params
  params.require(:doctor_profile).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password_digest, :specialty_id)
end
```

Comment: yeh, that's what I have now but was hoping there was a cleaner way :)